# Issue in changing mapred heap size in amazon elastic mapreduce job

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am new to Amazon Elastic MapReduce and I am struggling to set the mapred heap size to 1Gb using bootstrap configuration. I am using m1.large instances. I have tried the following bootstrap configuration but in vain:

1)

Action Name Memory Intensive Configuration

Path s3n://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configurations/latest/memory-intensive

Args

2)

Action Name Configure Hadoop

Path s3n://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop

Args --site-key-value io.file.buffer.size=65536 --mapred-key-value mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m

I am not sure what I've tried makes sense or not.

It would be great if any of you can guide me.
Thanks

Comment: This question has been modified as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024476/amazon-elastic-mapreduce-bootstrap-actions-not-working  Please help