# Amazon Elastic MapReduce Bootstrap Actions not working

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I have tried the following combinations of bootstrap actions to increase the heap size of my job but none of them seem to work:

```
--mapred-key-value mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m 
--mapred-key-value mapred.child.ulimit=unlimited

--mapred-key-value mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m 
--mapred-key-value mapred.map.child.ulimit=unlimited

-m mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m
-m mapred.map.child.ulimit=unlimited 

-m mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m 
-m mapred.child.ulimit=unlimited
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Thanks JMAx..please help

Answer (score 7):

You have two options to achieve this:

#### Custom JVM Settings

In order to apply custom settings, You might want to have a look at the [Bootstrap Actions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Bootstrap.html) documentation for [Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon EMR)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/), specifically action [Configure Daemons](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Bootstrap.html#PredefinedBootstrapActions_ConfigureDaemons):

> This predefined bootstrap action lets you specify the heap size or
>   other Java Virtual Machine (JVM) options for the Hadoop daemons. You
>   can use this bootstrap action to configure Hadoop for large jobs that
>   require more memory than Hadoop allocates by default. You can also use
>   this bootstrap action to modify advanced JVM options, such as garbage
>   collection behavior.

An example is provided as well, which *sets the heap size to 2048 and configures the Java namenode option*:

```
$ ./elastic-mapreduce –create –alive \
  --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-daemons \
  --args --namenode-heap-size=2048,--namenode-opts=-XX:GCTimeRatio=19
```

#### Predefined JVM Settings

Alternatively, as per the FAQ [How do I configure Hadoop settings for my job flow?](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#cluster-15), *if your job flow tasks are memory-intensive, you may choose to use fewer tasks per core and reduce your job tracker heap size. For this situation, a pre-defined Bootstrap Action is available to configure your job flow on startup* - this refers to action [Configure Memory-Intensive Workloads](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Bootstrap.html#PredefinedBootstrapActions_MemoryIntensive), which *allows you to set cluster-wide Hadoop settings to values appropriate for job flows with memory-intensive workloads*, for example:

```
$ ./elastic-mapreduce --create \
--bootstrap-action \
  s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configurations/latest/memory-intensive
```

The specific configuration settings applied by this predefined bootstrap action are listed in [Hadoop Memory-Intensive Configuration Settings](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HadoopMemoryIntensive.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Steffen, based on the documentation I have tried the above arguments on the "configure-hadoop" bootstrap script, but is not working. It would be great if you can give me the exact command for setting the "mapred.child.java.opts" heap size in mapred-site.xml configuration file of Hadoop

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I am able to set the other settings listed  "Hadoop Memory-Intensive Configuration Settings" except for "mapred.child.java.opts", thats why I am requesting for the exact argument/command.

Comment: @ShrishBajpai: You may want to try the alternative and supposedly easier approach first (see my updated answer), before diving deeper (this might offer some insight regarding your question as well); if you really need custom settings, I may look into this some more later on, but will be out of office for a couple of hours now, sorry.

Comment: @ShrishBajpai: Just reread your first comment - the listed `--namenode-heap-size=2048` option is to be used specifically with the _configure-daemons_ bootstrap action and won't work with the _configure-hadoop_ bootstrap action (as you already found out ;)

Comment: Thanks Steffen, but increasing the name ode heap size alone won't help. To confirm this I reran the job on m.xlarge instance with the following configure-hadoop bootstrap action:   --jobtracker-heap-size=3072 --namenode-heap-size=1024 --tasktracker-heap-size=512 --datanode-heap-size=no tracker and it failed with heap error again. To overcome this I need to be able to increase the mapred.child.java.opts heap size which I have tried on my local using native hadoop setup

Comment: @ShrishBajpai: You may want to read my previous comment again - `--namenode-heap-size=1024` **does not work with *configure-hadoop***, rather only with *configure-daemon.* To add some useful information from [Bootstrap Action Basics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Bootstrap.html#BootstrapUses) eventually: _You can specify up to 16 bootstrap actions per job flow by providing multiple --bootstrap-action parameters from the CLI or API._

Answer (score 0):

Steffen's answer is good and works. On the other hand if you just want something quick-and-dirty and  just want to replace one or two variables, then you're probably looking to just change it via the command line like the following:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create \
--bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop \
  --args "-m,mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx999m"
```

I've seen another documentation, albeit an older one, that simply quotes the entire expression within one quote like the following:

```
--bootstrap-action "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop -m \
    mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx999m"    ### I tried this style, it no longer works!
```

At any rate, this is not easily found in the [AWS EMR documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html). I suspect that mapred.child.java.opts is one of the most overridden variables-- I was also looking for an answer when I got a GC error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" and stumbled on this page. The default of 200m is just too small ([documentation on defaults](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)).

Good luck!